# R Shiny: how to use a dataframe variable from server.R in ui.R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the **values$df** dataframe variable from server.R in ui.R to display all the field names of the dataframe as checkbox in the side panel. But I get an error saying **Error: object 'values' not found**.

Here is what I have in the server.R file:

```
  values<- reactiveValues() 
  values$df<- data.frame() # creates an empty dataframe

  # actionButton 
  mdf<- eventReactive(input$click_counter, {
    name<- input$name
    gender<- input$gender
    college<- input$college
    team<- input$team
    score<- input$score

    new_row<- data.frame(name,college,gender,team,score)

    return(new_row)
  })

  observeEvent(input$click_counter, {
    name<- input$name
    gender<- input$gender
    college<- input$college
    team<- input$team
    score<- as.numeric(input$score) # convert to numeric here to make sorting possible
    rank<- 0


    new_row<- data.frame(rank,name,college,gender,team,score)


    values$df<- rbind(values$df, new_row)
    values$df<- values$df[order(-values$df$score),]
    values$df$rank<- 1:nrow(values$df)
  })

  output$nText<- renderDataTable({
    mdf()
  })

  output$nText2<- renderDataTable({
    values$df
  }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 30), pageLength = 5))
```

And this is what I have in the ui.R file:

```
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput('nText2',
                       'Columns in players to show:',
                       names(values$df),
                       selected = names(values$df))
  ),
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `values` anywhere in your code, so it can't run `rbind(values$df, new_row)`

Comment: I'd also recommend that you move your `checkboxGroupInput()` to the server side with `renderUI()` and then just call the `htmlOutput("nText2")` in the user interface.  This will allow the UI to be dependent on the outcome of the server side operation.  Calling the reactive value from the server in the UI as `values$df` is not generally how the UI interacts with the server.

Comment: You are trying to access `values` defined outside a reactive function. Try `isolate(values$df)` on UI side

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure when you assign the `values` object. However, if you are not already using a global.R file I suggest using one. In it you can assign `values` and the object will be available in both `server.R` and `ui.R`. Place global.R in the same folder as the two other files.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the server to render the UI allows you to continue working with the data frame as you are for other server side operations. Without having the data frame reproducible, I can't say for certain whether THIS data frame will work, but I hope this gives you a good push forward.

server.R:

```
output$nText2ui <- renderUI({checkboxGroupInput('nText2',
                          'Columns in players to show:',
                          names(values$df),
                          selected = names(values$df))
                         })
```

ui.R:

```
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
   htmlOutput("nText2ui")
    )
  )
```