# Select variables from a dataframe after on which operations are made

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm constructing a dashboard with Shiny and for a certain plot I want the user let choose which variable the plot will show.
So far I never had an issue with that but now, whyever, I always receive that the dataframe is not there to choose from.

I guess this might be due to the circumstance that this dataframe is created rather at the end of the entire code and when Shiny is building up the dashboard including the SelectVariable option, it does not know this dataframe, yet.

Does this make sense? On the other hand, I wonder then, why this had never been any issue before.
If my guessing is true, how do I solve this?

```
ui.R
library(shiny)

ui<- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(""),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("HiRay 9 DB"),
  
  tabsetPanel(               
    tabPanel("Histogram",
             sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(width = 3, sliderInput("bins"
                                                   ,"Number of bins:"
                                                   ,min = 100
                                                   ,max = 1000
                                                   ,value = 500
                                                   ),
                                      varSelectInput("sel_variable"
                                                 , "Choose variable: "
                                                 , data = df_sorted
                                                 , selected = "x_ray_hours_balance"
                                    #             , multiple = FALSE
                                                    )
                          ),
                   mainPanel(
                            plotOutput("histo", width = "100%", height = "500"),
                            plotOutput("ggpairs", width = "100%", height = "500")
                            )
                        )
              ),
    tabPanel("Unsorted data", 
              mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("Unsorted_data", width = "150%", height = "650"),
                        plotOutput("Unsorted_data2", width = "150%", height = "450")
                        )
             ),
    tabPanel("Sorted data", 
             mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("Sorted_data", width = "150%", height = "425"),
                        plotOutput("Sorted_data2", width = "150%", height = "425")
                      )
            ),
    tabPanel("Weibull", 
             mainPanel(
                      div("Loading might take a while, please stay put..", style = "color:blue")
                      , plotOutput("Weibull", width = "150%", height = "800")
                      )
            ),
    tabPanel("Survival", 
             mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("Survival", width = "150%", height = "800")
                      )
            ),
    tabPanel("Survival ext", 
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("Survival_ext", width = "150%", height = "800")
             )
            ),
    tabPanel("Correlations", 
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("Correlations", width = "150%", height = "800")
                      )
            ),
    tabPanel("PCA", 
             mainPanel(
                plotOutput("PCA", width = "150%", height = "800")
                )
            )
  )
)



server.R    
# Read in data ----
df = data.frame(read.csv("file.csv"
                         , header = TRUE
                         , sep = ";"
                         , dec = ","
                         , na.strings = "---"
                        )
                )


# clean data frame ----
df<- df %>%
          clean_names()
df<- df %>% janitor::remove_empty(whic=c("rows"))
df<- df %>% janitor::remove_empty(whic=c("cols"))
df<- dplyr::distinct(df)
colnames(df)[1]<- "country"
df_unsorted<- df


# sort out data ----
### keep only status, x_ray_hours_balance, preventive_exchange, operating_hours, op days, fail code
df<- df[, c("status"
            , "x_ray_hours_balance"
            , "preventive_exchange"
            , "position_in_unit"
            , "operating_hours_balance"
            , "operating_days"
            , "failure_code"
)]
df<- df[df$x_ray_hours_balance != "---", ]   
df<- df[!is.na(df$x_ray_hours_balance), ]
df<- df[!is.na(df$status), ]


# Make num columns numeric
df[, c(
       "x_ray_hours_balance"
       , "operating_hours_balance"
       , "operating_days"
        )]<- sapply(df[, c(
                           "x_ray_hours_balance"
                           , "operating_hours_balance"
                           , "operating_days"
                            )],as.numeric)

## keep x_ray > 0 ----
df<- subset(df, df$x_ray_hours_balance > 0)


## clean status ----
df<- df[df$status != "?", ]   
#df<- df[df$position_in_unit != "?", ]                                     
df_sorted<- df 
    

# Plot ----
server<- function(input, output) {

    output$histo <- renderPlot({
     p_1<- ggplot(df_sorted, aes_string(x = input$sel_variable)) + 
     # p_1<- ggplot(df_sorted, aes(x = input$sel_variable)) + 
     # p_1<- ggplot(df_sorted, aes_string(x = x_ray_hours_balance )) + 
     # p_1<- ggplot(df_sorted, aes(x = x_ray_hours_balance )) + 
         geom_histogram(binwidth = input$bins
                        , fill = "darkgreen"
                        , colour = "forestgreen"
         ) + theme_bw()
     p_1
     })
}
```

When I replace `df_sorted` with `df` within the ggplot command, it works. The same/similar question arose already here: [R Shiny: how to use a dataframe variable from server.R in ui.R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535554/r-shiny-how-to-use-a-dataframe-variable-from-server-r-in-ui-r)

Comment: A closing vote without any explanation or even a comment? nice.

Comment: I guess, the closing vote was raised to due missing code. If you would provide a minimal reproducable example which shows the problem, it would be easier to answer this question.

Comment: I thought I would make everyone's life easier by avoiding this ;) wait a moment

Comment: @Ben It would be nice to have a *minimal* and *reproducible* example: I'm sure that there is a lot of code here that isn't necessary to reproduce your problem. Also, you use `read.csv("file.csv")` but no one except you has this dataset. Can you please reduce the size of the example and provide an example with data that everyone can have (e.g using `mtcars`, or `dput()` on your data)?

Comment: Sorry, the data is confidential. I try to remove some code.

Comment: If you can't provide the data, then you should modify your example to use data that is available for everyone, so that we can also reproduce the problem. Otherwise, it is just impossible to run your code. Using a clean dataset that everybody has also allows you to remove all the code to clean the data, that is probably not useful in your problem here.

Comment: will do so, gimme' some minutes

Comment: Looking at your code: `df_unsorted` seems to be missing in your `ui` part.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, your `df` seems only be available within your server script. Below is a minimal example that reproduces your error. If you comment in the first line it will work:

```
library(shiny)

# without this line your script will fail - comment it in to make it work:
# df_iris <- iris

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 10,
              value = 1
              ),
  
  varSelectInput("sel_variable",
                 "Choose variable: ",
                 data = df_iris,
                 selected = "Sepal.Length"
  ),
  
  plotOutput("histo", width = "100%", height = "500")
  
), server = function(input, output) {
  
  df_iris <- iris
  
    output$histo <- renderPlot({
      
      p_1 <- ggplot(df_iris,
                    aes(x = !! input$sel_variable)) + 
        
        geom_histogram(binwidth = input$bins) +
        
        theme_bw()
      
      p_1
      
    })
    
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am using ui.R and server.R as two files and as far as I see/understand, the issue arises, while ui.R is set up, it doesn't know df_iris as this is constructed at the end of server.R

Comment: Wait, do I need to create the dataframe df_iris in both files? If so, then I wonder why it works with df simply, but not with any other named dataframe..?!